# How to align right when flex-wrap is triggered but justify-content space-between otherwise?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have searched for the answer but I am not sure how to write my question in a concise matter to find answers. So far, I have found nothing.

Here is the situation:

On large screen, I would like this:

```
edge| [CONTENT A] ... space ... [CONTENT B] |edge
```

I have achieve this by using `justify-content: space-between`.

However when the window resize down, the content become:

```
edge| [CONTENT A] ... space ... |edge
edge| [CONTENT B] ... space ... |edge
```

( I am using `flex-wrap: wrap`)

But I would like

```
edge| ... space ... [CONTENT A] |edge
edge| ... space ... [CONTENT B] |edge
```

- I have tried with `width: 100% ; text-align: right` but then in large screen the content look centered since the `content A` is pushed to the right.
- I have tried `margin-left: auto` and it achieves the same visual effect: works in small screen but `content A` looks centered in large width.
- I have tried `align-items: flex-end; align-content: flex-end` but it doesn't do anything.
- I have tried `align-self: flex-end` but it doesn't do anything either.

Any suggestions ?
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, have you used css media queries to have different css on smaller screens?

Comment: The content can change size. It is text that move around. Using media query will be extremely painful and not reliable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`row-reverse wrap-reverse` can do it

```css
.box {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap-reverse;
  /* OR
     flex-direction: row-reverse;
     flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  */
  
  /* to illustrate */
  overflow:hidden;
  resize:horizontal;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid;
  /**/
}

.box > div {
  padding:10px 30px;
  border:1px solid blue;
} 

.box > div:first-child {
  order:1; /* to rectify the order swapped by row-reverse */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div>some text A</div>
<div>some text B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow ! This is brilliant ! I didnt even know `wrap-reverse` existed and I would have never thought of using it in combination with `row-reverse` while reversing my DOM. This is crazy haha. Thank you so much !